# Cocoa bindings to one window with IBAction and IBOutlet in different classes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, kvc

I am trying to implement an `IBAction` in one class (`SuperDel`) and access `IBOutlet` in another class (`SubC`).

The class method `subMethod` is suppose to change the value of NSString `test`in the viewer via KVC/KVO .

From the Object Library in Xcode I have added a controller object and linked it to custom class `SubC`. Then I bind `test` to `SubC` such that the Key Path is Value(SubC.test) in the bindings Inspector.

- When I call `subMethod` from `SubC` via `(IBAction)startC` everything works fine.
- When I call `subMethod` from `SuperDel` via `(IBAction)start` only NSLog displays.

It appears as the reciever `self` in `subMethod` is the root/cause of the problem, since the problem only appears when I call the method from another class (`SuperDel`).

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE1:**
I have made several variants of the toy code below and the problem remains. 
I just can't get KVO and Cocoa-bindings to work unless I have IBAction and IBOutlet in the same m-file.
`@stevesliva`'s advice seem to indicate that `self` isn't the problem, since `NSLog` displays the correct class

**UPDATE2:** `_test` updates correctly and `self` points to the correct class.
The only thing left is this line of code: `[self didChangeValueForKey:@"test"]`, but this line shouldn't be necessary...

The view is correctly updated when the `IBAction` calls `subMethod` from within the `SubC` class; The view is *never* updated when `IBAction` is called from another class…  and I have no idea why not.

Please help, this is driving me crazy.

***SuperDel.h:***

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface SuperDel: NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender;
@end
```

***SuperDel.h:***

```
#import "SuperDel.h"
#import "SubC.h"
@implementation SuperDel
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {
    SubC *parc = [[SubC alloc]init];
    [parc subMethod];
}
@end
```

***SubC.h:***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface SubC : NSObject {
//    NSString *test;                           
}
@property NSString *test;
//- (IBAction)startC:(id)sender;
- (void)subMethod;
@end
```

***SubC.m:***

```
#import "SubC.h"
@implementation SubC
@synthesize test;                             
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setValue:@"*" forKey:@"test"];
    }
    return self;
}
/*
- (IBAction)startC:(id)sender {
    [self subMethod];   
}
*/
- (void)subMethod{    
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"test"];     // Shouldn't be necessary
    [self setValue:@"Foo" forKey:@"test"];    // This only changes View if the method is called from within the class, i.e. via (IBAction)startC
    NSLog(@"test = %@", _test);               // This always results in: test = Foo
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"test"];      // Shouldn't be necessary
    NSLog(@"Self = %@", self);                // Self = <SubC: 0x10014ae30>
    NSLog(@"This always displays");           // This displays regardless if called from (IBAction)startC or (IBAction)start
}
@end
```

Comment: I happen to have the book.  For purposes of illustration, they're declaring the backing iVar for the property, which isn't really necessary and isn't standard, and that's what I was harping on. I thought maybe you were calling the `test` accessor rather that the `setTest` setter somehow. Regardless, the reason I'm not answering is that I don't know what's causing the issue you describe, and also assuming this code here is a synopsys of what you really have.  It may be that you have multiple instances of SubC objects, and you're thinking you have fewer.  You could NSLog the address of `self`.

Comment: It is the toy code of the real code. but the toy code displays the same problem as the real code. If I can't get the toy code to work I won't be able to get the real code to work. Tried NSLog as you suggested, see above

Comment: Are you still trying to solve this? If you are, can you clarify a few things: **firstly** when you talk about changing the value of ``test`` *in the viewer*, what do you mean by *viewer*? **secondly**, what kind of *controller object* did you add (i.e. what is its specific class), and **thirdly** what do you mean by '*linked it to custom class*'? Questions that mix bindings, kvo/kvc, and interface builder can be tricky to help with unless you're very precise about the set-up.